# How do I import from current app in Django without using the app name?

Tags: django, django-models, import

My app is full of statements like this:

```
from my_app.model import Customer
```

While it works, I'll like to have a way to reference the current app without hard coding the app name into the import. Something like:

```
from keyword_for_current_app.model import Customer
```

Is there a clean way of achieving this with Django?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a python question than a Django one as it relates to how imports work. As far as I know, there isn't a way to do it as you describe, unless you change the structure of your files.

However, it isn't impossible to do something using Django's functionality to dynamically import models. You could swap some of this with `importlib` if you need a more general import rather than just returning the model class:

```py
from django.apps import apps

# option 1
model = apps.get_model('app.Model') 

# option 2
def get_model(model_name):
   return apps.get_model(f'myapp.{model_name}')

# option 3
def get_model(model_name):
   for model in apps.get_models():
      if model.__name__ == model_name:
         return model
```

The problem with option 1 for your use case is that you still need to specify the app name. Option 2 is an improvement, but you are hardcoding the app name into the function. Option 3 is the best, but might be problematic if you have models with the same name but in different apps/tables.

In my opinion, you should import each model explicitly at the top of your files. This is the cleanest and most readable way - if someone were to read your code, they would expect models to be imported this way.